# Apache flink CEP library issue (cluster)

Tags: apache-flink, complex-event-processing

I have a fairly simple app running fine in Eclipse. When deployed to a cluster it fails very quickly with this:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not look up the main(String[])
>   method from the class org.ice.drmcl.Application:
>   org/apache/flink/cep/pattern/conditions/IterativeCondition

Only happen if I include pattern matching code, e.g. like this:

```
Pattern<TransferMonitor, ?> pattern = Pattern.<TransferMonitor>begin("start")
    .where(new SimpleCondition<TransferMonitor>() {
        // ...
    });
```

Both Eclipse and Cluster are running Flink v1.3.2

Answer (score 2):

Oh look - why don't you read the manual....:-
"Note that FlinkCEP is currently not part of the binary distribution."

That might explain why it cannot find your class as its actually not there. Shakes head.

Comment: I was wondering if ./bin/flink run ./WordCount.jar  can run as provided by Flink, so can I run my own  custom made Flink CEP jar